# How would I go about running NSTimer while still allowing console input from the user?

Tags: objective-c, grand-central-dispatch, nstimer, objective-c++, nsrunloop

Long story short, I'm trying to create a simple console game that allows the user to input commands into the console in order to perform actions (such as start/stop) while at the same time printing out various properties and actions into the console.

```
    _gameDispatchQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    dispatch_async(_gameDispatchQueue, ^{
                       _propertyTimer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 0.1
                                               target: mairne
                                               selector: @selector(printProperties:)
                                               userInfo: nil
                                               repeats: YES];
                       [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];
                   });
```

And in my main.mm file I accept input via `cin` and then accept on it when they hit enter.

My issue with this code is that despite me trying to put it in a background thread, it still won't allow the user to input anything and hit enter. So for example if they want to write `stop` and hit enter, the command doesn't get processed.

How do I get NSTimer to run in the background printing things, but still allow user input to be processed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running the timer on the main thread but inside your selector printProperties, have it run all of its contents in a dispatch queue like so:

```
// Init these somewhere on the main thread
_bgQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.yourco.yourapp.bgQueue", NULL);
_propertyTimer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 0.1
                                               target: mairne
                                               selector: @selector(printProperties:)
                                               userInfo: nil
                                               repeats: YES];

- (void)printProperties:(id)sender
{
   dispatch_async(_bgQueue, ^{
      // do your work here
   }
}
```

Comment: As you can see with the target being different, printProperties is in a different class than when `_propertyTimer` is created. How would printProperties know of the _bgQueue?

Comment: Ah good point. the target would have to be self in this case, assuming _bgQueue and _propertyTimer are initialized in -(id)init

Answer (score 1):

To expand somewhat on bbum's answer, `NSFileHandle` actually has a nice Objective-C API that wraps setting up a `dispatch_source`.

You can get an `NSFileHandle` for `stdin` like so:

```
 NSFileHandle *standardInputHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleWithStandardInput];
```

`NSFileHandle` has a property called `readabilityHandler` that takes a block to be called (asynchronously) when data comes in. So, you can do something like this:

```
standardInputHandle.readabilityHandler = ^(NSFileHandle *fileHandle) { handleUserInputData([fileHandle availableData]); };
```

Assuming you can/want to handle incoming data line by line (ie. a return/newline is always the end of a command), this will probably work for you as is.

Answer (score 1):

It's worth to try to use ncurses for such kind of console apps. `getch` with `nodelay` works as non-blocking key input.

```
 void initialize_function() {
     nodelay(stdscr, TRUE);
 }

 void function_will_be_called_from_NSRunLoop() {
      int ch;
      if ((ch = getch()) != ERR) {
          /*
           * user has pressed a key ch, pool it into a queue for parsing command
           * like start, stop, or something like that
           */
      }

      /*
       * print out various properties and actions into the ncurses screen (the console)
       */
 }
```

- [ncurses 5.9](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/)
- [Ncurses Programming Guide](http://hughm.cs.ukzn.ac.za/~murrellh/os/notes/ncurses.html)

Answer (score 0):

Move the reading from `stdin` off the main thread.  Or, possibly, use a `dispatch_source` attached to the `stdin` file handle to provide a callback when data is available (buffering may be tricky).

Comment: By only doing I/O operations on `stdin` on some other thread/queue.  Or use the solution that Kazuki recommends.

Comment: For example, would accepting input into `stdin` via a `dispatch_async` queue work?